# High charts remove dots from the line graph

Tags: api, graph, highcharts

I am using High charts to draw a line graph. I cant find any thing in the API to remove the dots from the line. Please share if you know which bit of settings to change to remove the dots.

http://gyazo.com/ba33b6a6cc1a3898fee00b737111da4c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the bit you need to edit is the marker:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.marker.enabled

You should be able to set that to false and that'll hide the dots.

Answer (score 22):

You just have to disable the markers, which is demonstrated here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-enabled/

```
chart.plotOptions.line.marker.enabled = false
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  Consider up-voting answers you find helpful and correct.

Comment: I cant up vote yet, need 15 points at least. :(